# Keyframe cannot be animated back

Tags: css

I have a keyframe and 2 buttons. When clicking on the forward button, I want my box to move forwards and when clicking on the back button, I want to reverse my keyframe, so the box should move back.

This is what I have tried:

```js
const box = document.querySelector('.box');
document.getElementById('right').addEventListener('click', () => {
    box.classList.add('active');
});

document.getElementById('left').addEventListener('click', () => {
    box.style.animationDirection = 'reverse';
        // Also tried it with: box.classList.remove('active');
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
}

.active {
  animation: move 1s forwards;
}


@keyframes move {
  from {
    left: 0;
  }
  to {
    left: 20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="left">&lt;</button>
<button id="right">&gt;</button>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use two different animations assigned to two different classes and just add and remove them like a pseudo toggle

```js
const box = document.querySelector('.box');
document.getElementById('right').addEventListener('click', () => {
  box.classList.remove('moveLeft');
  box.classList.add('moveRight');
});

document.getElementById('left').addEventListener('click', () => {
  box.classList.remove('moveRight');
  box.classList.add('moveLeft');
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
}

.active {
  animation: move 1s forwards;
}

.moveRight {
  animation: moveRight 1s forwards;
}

.moveLeft {
  animation: moveLeft 1s forwards;
}

@keyframes moveRight {
  from {
    left: 0;
  }
  to {
    left: 20px;
  }
}

@keyframes moveLeft {
  from {
    left: 20px;
  }
  to {
    left: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="left">&lt;</button>
<button id="right">&gt;</button>
<div class="box"></div>
```

You could use a transition as well if you're not set on using keyframes. Same result, two different methods

```js
const box = document.querySelector('.box');
document.getElementById('right').addEventListener('click', () => {
  box.classList.add('active');
});

document.getElementById('left').addEventListener('click', () => {
  box.classList.remove('active');
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

.active {
  transform: translateX(20px);
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<button id="left">&lt;</button>
<button id="right">&gt;</button>
<div class="box"></div>
```